# Ariane 5 performance data for escape missions

Tags: interplanetary, reference-request, ariane, performance, specifications

I would like to know the performance for escape mission of the Ariane 5 launcher. More precisely, I would like "LV Performance vs. C 3" curve.
My problem is, I can find this info for a lot of launchers but not Ariane. Does anybody have such plot or, at least the value for low C3 (around 0-4)?

[image: Soyuz curve]
Here the kind of plot I would like. This one is for Soyuz and I found it in the [Soyuz user's manual](http://www.arianespace.com/launch-services-soyuz/Soyuz_Users_Manual_CSG_June06.pdf) but this is not in the [Ariane one's](http://www.arianespace.com/launch-services-ariane5/Ariane5_users_manual_Issue5_July2011.pdf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Ariane 5 user manual has the following data:

> Using a storable propellant upper stage, through a delayed ignition of this upper stage, Ariane 5, in the A5G version, has demonstrated its ability to carry a satellite weighing 3065 kg, leading to a total required performance of 3190 kg, towards the following earth escape orbit:
>    - infinite velocity V∞ = 3545 m/s
>    - declination δ = - 2°
>
> The typical Ariane 5ECA performance on a similar orbit is 4.3 t.

No graph though.

C$_3$ = (V∞)$^2$. And V∞ is related to payload mass via the rocket equation, so you should be able to draw a plot using this one data point. I've no time to do that today though.

Comment: Yes, I found only information like that. Is it possibilities to extrapolate these data for interplanetary mission?

Comment: I think so, yes. See the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: The rocket equation assume there is no extern forces. I do you take account of drag, gravity and others forces due to the Earth and atmosphere? Do you know a good model for this?

Comment: Well, you have one data point that takes those forces into account. I expect you can plug that into the rocket equation and get reasonably close. The rocket equation will set the shape of the V∞/m curve, your data point will set the starting point. But that's just an assumption. I recommend you ask a new question about how to calculate these curves, that might trigger an answer from someone who knows more than me.

Comment: I didn't think about that! I'll try it and eventually ask another question. Thanks you very much!